# Why did this happen to Laurie Bream?

Tags: plot-explanation, silicon-valley

In the season finale of Silicon Valley, they show Pied Piper's former investor, Laurie Bream in prison. Why did she go to prison?

[image: Laurie Bream in prison]

Comment: Please try to avoid spoilers in question titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is deliberately left unexplained by the show creators [to possibly give her character a comical/amusing end].

In an [interview](https://tvline.com/2019/12/08/silicon-valley-recap-series-finale-season-6-episode-7-erlich-dies/) with TVLine, executive producer Alec Berg, who wrote and directed the last episode of the series, had the following to say in relation to Laurie Bream's imprisonment:

> TVLINE | Laurie Bream is in prison. What did they get her for in the end?
>   That was a deliberate decision to [not reveal what landed here in jail]. The one conversation we had to have about what she [was convicted of was related to] what she was wearing. In minimum security prisons people wear tan jumpsuits. And in medium and high security [prisons] they wear orange [jumpsuits]. I got a call from the wardrobe people [asking], “What did Laurie get convicted of?” Ultimately, it came down to orange because I think it’s funnier. Whatever she did it merited an orange jumpsuit.